# Debug PHP 5.6 Using xdebug 2.5.5 Running in a docker container in VS Code

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, xdebug

I am running a PHP app in a docker container. PHP 5.6, and xdebug 2.5.5 and using vscode with the PHP Debug v1.34.0 extension.

I have added this to my php.ini:

```
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
xdebug.remote_log=/tmp/x_debug.log
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=9001
xdebug.idekey="VSC"
zend_extension=xdebug.so
```

I've tried changing some of the values to:

```
xdebug.idekey=docker
xdebug.remote_host=host.docker.internal
```

I have PHP Debug listening on port 9001 as well.

However, none of my breakpoints are being hit.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: PHP 5.6? AYFKM?

Comment: Your config is trying to connect to a debugger inside the container on port 9001. Are you running your debugger inside the container?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the mentioned versions have been unsupported for nearly a decade.

Comment: `127.0.0.1` is clearly wrong, but `host.docker.internal` only works if you're running Docker Desktop. Is that the case? If not, you'll need to [obtain the actual IP address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach). Aside that, you don't say if something gets logged to `/tmp/x_debug.log`; for that, you may need to increase log level.

Comment: @Derick I don't think there's any policy to hide or archive old information, as long as it's correct. Maintaining and upgrading legacy systems is already hard enough, why do it without resources or documentation?

Comment: Xdebug 2's logging is pretty useless, but my guess is that you don't have path mappings configured, or configured correctly. Xdebug does also not care about the IDE Key value.